# React Highcharts piechart show tooltip on click outside of highcharts container

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, click, tooltip

I am having a "Donutchart" using highcharts and a selfmade legend for that chart. When i click on an element of the legend, i want to trigger the "mouseOver" or "click" event of that container, so that the chart shows the respective area, belonging to the element of the legend. Basically i want the tooltip to show up.

The Piechart Code:

```
let chartOptions = {
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: 0,
            plotShadow: false,
        },
        title: {
            text: `Title`,
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                    distance: -125,
                    y: -5,
                    format: "{y}%",
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: "bold",
                        color: "black",
                        fontSize: "12px",
                    },
                },
                borderWidth: 3,
            },
            series: {
                animation: false,
            },
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
        },
        series: [
            {
                type: "pie",
                name: "",
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2,
                    valueSuffix: " USD",
                },
                innerSize: "60%",
                data: data_array,
            },
        ],
    };
```

Example button:

```
<div className='mb_3px mt_3px cursor_pointer color_blue'
   onClick={() => {
       handleSimulateMouseOver(
           item.index
       );
   }}
>
   {truncate(
       object[
           item.index
       ].name,
       39
   )}
</div>
```

In older posts i found a function called setState('hover'), which i can't bring to work in react, that looks like the following:

```
let handleSimulateMouseOver= (index) => {
    chartOptions.series[0].data[index].setState('hover');
    chartOptions.tooltip.refresh(chartOptions.series[0].data[index]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an event to trigger callback after legend item click - API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.events.legendItemClick

Have you tried to use it?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If i get this right, this would help me if i used the legend provided by highcharts. In this case, i created my own legend, that is not directly next to the chart, but still on the same page.

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on some online editor to see how it works?